# Python regex does not search with group numbering

Tags: python, regex

I am trying out the example given in http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for the group numbering and matching. Very simply, `(.+) \1` should match two pieces of identical text separated by a space, and it lists `the the` as an example. However,

```
 re.search('(.+) \1','the the')
```

returns a `None`.

I am using `re` version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to escape your escapes or use raw strings.
e.g.

```
re.search('(.+) \\1', 'the the' )
```

or

```
re.search(r'(.+) \1', 'the the' )
```

see the Raw String Notation section on the same page as the example.

Answer (score 5):

`'\1'` is `'\x01'`. Perhaps you meant `'(.+) \\1'` or `r'(.+) \1'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using named groups like these:

```
(?P=name)
```

So in this case I would recommend using named patterns and doing this:

```
re.search('(?P<first_match>.+) (?P=first_match)', 'the the')
```